# API taking too long, map function firing before data loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withProvider} from './TProvider'
import ThreeCardMap from './ThreeCardMap';

class Threecard extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            newlist: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getList()
        this.setState({newlist: [this.props.list]})
    }

    // componentDidUpdate() {
    //     console.log(this.state.newlist);
    // }
    render() {
        const MappedTarot = (this.state.newlist.map((list, i) => <ThreeCardMap key={i} name={list.name} meaningup={list.meaning_up} meaningdown={list.meaning_rev}/>);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Three Card Reading</h1>
                <div>{ MappedTarot }</div>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
export default withProvider(Threecard);
```

Hi, I'm trying to create a page that takes data from a tarot card API (https://rws-cards-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards/search?type=major). Unfortunately by the time the data comes in, my map function has already fired. I'm asking to see if there is a way to have the map function wait until the data hits before it fires. Thanks!

Edit: getList function in the Context:

```
 getList = () => {
        console.log('fired')
        axios.get('https://vschool-cors.herokuapp.com?url=https://rws-cards-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/cards/search?type=major').then(response =>{
            this.setState({
                list: response.data
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can I see what in the `getList` function?

Comment: Sure, added the get list function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.props.getList() is an async function. You are setting the list right after that call which is not correct.
You need to set it in the getList promise then() block.

Answer (score 1):

`getList()` is an async function and update data for the parent component. So, my solution is just watching the `list` from the parent component if they updated or not, through [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```js
class Threecard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state = {
        newlist: []
      }
    }
    
  // Set props.list to this.state.newList and watch the change to update
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    return {
      newlist: nextProps.list
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getList()
    // Removed this.setState() from here.
  }

  render() {
    const MappedTarot = (this.state.newlist.map((list, i) => <ThreeCardMap key={i} name={list.name} meaningup={list.meaning_up} meaningdown={list.meaning_rev}/>);
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Three Card Reading</h1>
          <div>{ MappedTarot }</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withProvider(Threecard);
```